# public rest service

Tags: rest-api, integration, webservices, force.com-sites, rest

I have a requirement to create a publicly accessible web service.

This is what I did

1)      Set up a Site on my org called publicWebService

https://sandbox.cs14.force.com/publicWebService/

2)      I create a class to handle a post http request

@RestResource(urlMapping='/logService/v1')

3)      I grated access to this class  in the sites profile

I set it up in my sandbox first and it works perfectly

Access as follows

https://sandbox.cs14.force.com/publicWebService/services/apexrest/logcall/v1?parm1=blabla&parm2=haha

When i moved my implementation into my production org. I did the same thing.

But i can’t access it like i did in my sandbox

https:// production.force.com/publicWebService/services/apexrest/logcall/v1?parm1=blabla&parm2=haha

Am I missing something or have to do something differently

Much appreciated

Comment: What eror you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the site details page in your production org, in the "Custom URLs" section I think you will see a domain name that ends **secure.force.com** rather than **force.com**. Use that **secure.force.com** one for your production org.

(This difference has caused us problems when moving from a sandbox to production in the past.)